# How to serve MS office documents inline instead of as attachment?

Tags: java, servlets, ms-office, mime-types

I want to serve MS documents inline instead of providing it as download by an attachment. I defined application mime type according to document type but the client still tries to download it. Here is my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    String fileName = "file.docx";

    try {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/"+fileName);

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to render a raw MS document inside a page, unless there is some client side plugin which allows this (similar to what Flash provides for videos and games). I am not aware of such a plugin though.  You will probably need to convert the document to HTML, and write that back to the client.

Comment: It is possible to render a MS document inside a page by using an object tag. But in this case there is no HTML Page. If content dispostion `inline` is used the client is expected to open the application for the mime-type and not to ask for a download location. If the mime type is unknown to the client the client may ask for a download location.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to use the `object` HTML Tag to embed an MS-Word or Excel document into an HTML page but I don't know how portable that is, even on Windows, between the different Browsers. Also you would perhaps have to got for HTML Frames to keep it limited to a  certain area on your page.

If that's not what you want you could either convert it yourself using some library or use an API like the ones from [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/developers) or [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/developers) which allow you to upload documents - also in MS formats - and get back an embeddable snippet. Though then your data is on hosted by their service.

Answer (score 0):

At least the Internet Explorer allows the user to [overwrite the disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773385/files-served-with-content-disposition-inline-still-sometimes-prompt-for-downloa).
Which Browsers have you used for testing?

The data you write to the output stream may be incomplete because `in.available()` may be less than the filesize.  From the JavaDoc of InputStream

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   invocation of a method for this input stream.

If you want to read the whole block use the File size from the file object.
It's also a good idea to tell the client the size of the file.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    String fileName = "file.docx";
    BufferedInputStream in = null;

    try {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/"+fileName);
        // not the best way
        int length = (int)file.length();

        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        // may allocate a huge ammout of memory
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();
        in = null;

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"%s\" ; size=\"%d\"", fileName, length));

        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServletException(e);
    } finally { 
       if (in != null) {
          try {
             in.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              // ignore 
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Whispered here's another [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment). Disposition 'inline' is only a hint for the browsers. For example in Firefox the user can overwrite the behavior in Settings->Applications. Have you allready tried it with different browsers using their default settings?